# How do you Render With Lots of Noise and With High Quality Anti-Aliasing in Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, antialiasing

If I make Cycles render at a low sample count, then there are not that many anti-aliasing samples.

If I make Cycles render at a higher sample count, then there are more anti-aliasing samples and generally less noise.

How you render with the path tracing noise of low sample count rendering, and with the anti-aliasing quality of high sample count rendering?

I thought about making all of the lighting in the scene be caustics, but it might not have enough noise at enough samples for high quality anti-aliasing.

Maybe doing something like [this](https://bensimonds.com/2013/03/04/cycles-experiment-pinhole-camera/) would work.

Is there a better way, like some way to arrange the samples, such that it makes lots of noise and high quality anti-aliasing?

If so, how?

Comment: I know in other render engines, anti aliasing samples are synonymous with overall samples, but I think now all of Cycles' sampling is controlled by one sample value.

Answer (score 0):

There is an anti-aliasing node in compositing. Have you tried rendering with few samples and then post-processing the result with that node?

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/anti_aliasing.html

Comment: That node might not produce anti-aliasing that looks like anti-aliasing with the box pixel filter.

Comment: Also, If I render something at more than one samples per pixel, such as 2 samples per pixel, then there would be 2 anti-aliasing applied to the render. Also, using the node to do it seems kind of hacky.